# Certain Page on website will not display after deployment

Tags: vue.js, heroku, web-deployment

I managed to deploy my first website through Heroku, but when I click on an icon to see another page (Current Projects page), it won't display - I get a "Cannot Get CurrentProjects". I did some research and found it could potentially be that my Vue.Js router, which is currently in History mode, might need to be changed.  Does anyone know where I can find information on how to change that? I've done some research and no luck. I have also attached my router.js page.  Any help or leads is appreciated.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import CurrentProjects from './views/CurrentProjects.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/CurrentProjects',
      name: 'CurrentProjects',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/CurrentProjects.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Can you show your deployment code? Do you use `static.json` file?